# Flagging versus Closing a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I have had spent a while on Stack Overflow, and I came across a situation where I am not sure what to do with flagging duplicate questions.

I have gone thorough the following already asked questions:

1. [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)
2. [Closing Duplicate Questions on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243744/closing-duplicate-questions-on-stackoverflow)

Based on above similar questions, I can't find the difference.

I have got the following options:

- **Close** : **`Why should this question be closed?`**

[image]

- **Flag** : **`I am flagging to report this question as...`**

[image]

Which one to choose?

---

**Edit**

So, if I understand correctly, for users with 3000+ reputation, even if the flag is raised for marking the question as duplicate, it will be converted as vote to close.

And, if someone runs out of votes to close, the flag still can't/shouldn't be used?

Comment: You should vote to close as long as you have votes. Otherwise, wait until the next day, and then vote to close.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker _"as long as you have votes"_ You'll not be able to use a _flag as duplicate_, if you're out of close votes IIRC. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why would I correct you? You're saying the exact same thing I am. If you can't vote to close; wait until the next day. The end.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: You're saying "You should vote". The other commenter is saying "You can't flag". I'm reading _completely_ different statements.

Comment: @NisseEngström I'm saying "You should vote *to close*". That's a specific action on our site. I'm saying if you ever have the privileges to vote to close something, you should not be flagging it for a reason you'd normally vote to close it for. In short: If you physically have the privilege to vote to close something, don't flag it for closure; even if you're out of close votes.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If you shouldn't flag it for closing when you're out of close votes, then why does the system allow you to? At least, that's what I think the others are trying to ask of you.

Comment: @mason The system *doesn't* allow you to flag for closure if you're out of close votes.  It tells you that you're out of close votes when you try to cast such a flag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you flag a question for closure the system will simply treat it as a vote to close instead of a flag, if you have close voting privileges.  Because of this, you're simply accessing the exact same functionality from two different places when you compare the flag to close vs. the close vote pages.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's correct, assuming the user has enough rep to *also* cast a close vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote as this answer is a good explanation, but the help section explicitly says the Vote to Close should be preferred over flagging. Even though they are functionally equivilant, this general advice helps avoid users accidentally choosing one of the more generic flag paths that would result in moderator attention: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: @Servy - Thanks for the answer. So, if I understand correctly, for users with 3000+ reputation, even if the flag is raised for marking the question as duplicate, it will be converted to vote to close.